# Is it possible to close browser tab in android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-browser

I have an app which plays music from a `local server` and opens `music player` in the `web browser` but when the user goes back to the `Home activity` and launches `Another activity` which plays a video on the browser, The video opens in a different tab of the browser, while music tab does not get closed.

Can I close an already opened browser tab when another tab opens?  If not. Please suggest some workarounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lots of struglling ,i reached on conclusion,we cant handle the operation of other application without permission by owner of application,so i have found alternet solution using webview now its working.

Comment: Could you please give more details how you did it? maybe with few code snippets would be awesom

Comment: @adi can u tell me your problem in detail

Comment: I want to do this too - please share how you did it. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442658/android-chrome-shortcut-to-close-browser-tabs

Comment: I did it using some peice of code.i will post here when i will be with my PC. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can't control another applications life-cycle . so you can't close tabs that are running in the browser.

what you can do on the other hand is to use [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) to open the audio/video
then you have full control over it (what and when) to load/close content.

Comment: Except webview is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

it isn;t the good way to do so, if you are interested in this then the code would be like this

```
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> list = servMng.getRunningAppProcesses();
if(list != null){
 for(int i=0;i<list.size();++i){
  if("com.android.browser".matches(list.get(i).processName)){
   int pid = android.os.Process.getUidForName("com.android.browser");
         android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
  }
 }
}
```