# android chrome shortcut to close browser tabs

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, android-activity, tasker

On android tablet using chrome there is no command to close all tabs.  My mother will often have 20+tabs open and it slows/crashes chrome.

I'd like to create a shortcut, but don't know if there are any action and intents to have chrome close all tabs (I can call it with tasker for example.)

Silly, infuriating problem but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

@aaronmallen yes, it can. Using AutoRemote plugin for tasker all kind of actions can be programmed for automated interaction with UI (clicking, swiping, typing, scrolling etc etc)

Answer (score -1):

1. Tap on the `tabs` button on the top right (the one that shows the number of open tabs). This will show you all the tabs in a stack.
2. Tap on the Settings button on the top right that is represented by 3 vertical dots.
3. You will see a few options. One of them will be `Close all tabs`. That option should close all your open tabs.

Comment: The OP is looking for a command line way to do this. Tasker cannot manipulate the UI in this way.